# How can I run selenium webdriver with two different users?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a small python script on my Ubuntu server to run a chrome browser in headless mode and open a url (see the script below). Currently I have two different users on my server: Let’s say user1 and user2.

**What I want to achieve:**

1. Login with user1 and user2 (two terminal sessions)
2. Start the script from user1, when finished
3. Start the script from user2

Everything works fine if I start the script with user1.

```
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

def getChromeDriver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("window-size=1900,1080")
    s = Service("/home/dev/chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=s)
    return driver

driver = getChromeDriver()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

time.sleep(3)
driver.quit()
```

When I switch to user2 with `su - user2` and start the script I get the error message: `DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist`. I need to restart the server to get the script executed from user2. But then I can’t execute the Script from user1 (same problem). Curiously, it works when I run the script as root (without restart).

So in short: It seems like I can only run the script with the user that executed the script for the first time after a server restart.

Any help or hints are appreciated.

Regards, Debo

Comment: create a new `driver` for each url

Comment: a `driver` is inited with a default guest user, by using multiple drivers, then you can have multiple users

Comment: Thank you for your reply @DeanVanGreunen. I tried this but it doesnt work. It seems like the webdriver is kinda blocked for other users  (except root) until I restart the server...

Comment: Do you want new users for new URLs? Why do you need multiple users? Perhaps there's another solution that involves only one user.

Comment: @JoshHeaps, for my purpose it's important that I execute the script with two different (non-root) users on the same machine (not at the same time). With one user I can execute the script many times without issues.  Really frustrating :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that only `user1` has rights on `/tmp/Crashpad`, because this user created the folder in the first place. `root` can read/write anywhere, so with the root user it works. Your `user2` cannot read/write from/to `/tmp/Crashpad` and this leads to the error message.

To check if user specific tmp dirs will resolve your problem, you can issue `chmod -R 777 /tmp/Crashpad` after running the script with `user1`. This  will make the folder read/writeable to anyone. Then try to run your script with `user2` and it should work.

On Ubuntu, you can set user specific tmp dirs by adding the line
`export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp`
to the `.profile` or the `.bashrc` file located in the users `$HOME` folder.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, that solved the problem. User2 had no permissions to access the directory  /tmp/Crashpad :/